# Closure of event listeners not working with multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

So i'm coding an implementation for movable SVG Objects. (I do  want to do this on my own, as i need some special features)
For each SVG i have a JS-Object with extra data etc..
In the constructor i'm creating a SVG-Element and append it to the SVG.

```
var self; // maybe this is a problem? I need it for prototyping and the whole code is wrapped in a factory function

var Scooter = function(id) {
    this.id = id; // this is just n-th instance
    this.svgElement = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "g");
    // doing some extra svg stuff
    SVG.appendChild(this.svgElement);

    self = this; // need this for the listener

    // **1**
}
```

Now i want to add the draggable feature, so i'm binding an event listener still in the constructor. (see `**1**` in the code sample above)

```
$(self.svgElement).on("mousedown", function(e) {
    // do sth for making it draggable
    console.log(self);
}
```

Ok. Now if i'm creating an instance, it works fine. When i'm adding a second instance, everything seems still fine. I can move the second one, like it's supposed to be. But if i'm dragging the first one again, it will move the second (or last created) object around!
Each SVG-Element is perfectly displayed and i thought each would have its own handler. But if i inspect the closure variables of the handler from the first object, `self` will now give me the reference to the latest object.
Can someone please explain why this happens and maybe suggest a work-around?

Comment: your self variable point always to the last instance created.. also why do you need this global self?

Comment: The self is not totally global. I need it because im adding prototype functions to the object, where is need a self reference. And in the prototyping the self reference always works perfectly. So i don't expect the problem to be this "global" self. But i'm not a js-master so if im wrong please tell me how i can get it running.

Comment: well it seems to me that self is shared by all the instances

Comment: Yep. Put `var self = this;` inside the constructor function, not outside.

Comment: Ok. I thought to remember that i used this 'self' as reference in the prototyping because 'this' did not work there... maybe i'm wrong. I have to Check this tomorow. Thank you so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

well something like

```
var Something = (function(){
   //constructor
   function Something(){
     ....
   }

   Something.prototype = {
     func1: function() {
     },
     func_n: function() {
     }
   };
   return something;
})()
```

no self

Comment: If i put a 'self' just before your constructor here every 'Something' should have its own 'self' right?